# How do I keep all the rows in a DataTable in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, datatable

I'm using a DataTable. And this table  I am adding data to DataTable using this code: **t.row.add ([...]). Draw (false);** Here is what I need: I want to print an alert on the screen if there is an r_name with the same name already registered.
For this I want to keep the r_name of all the rows in a array. And I want to compare the name of the newly added row with this array.If there is a r_name equal to each other, I want to make a warning on the screen. How can I do this?

```
var t = $('#datatables').DataTable();

//-------------------------INSERT ROOM START----------------------------
$("[name='add-room-submit']").click(function () {

    var r_name = document.getElementById('room-name').value;
    var r_plan = document.getElementById('image-path').value;

    t.row.add([
               '<div class="img-container">' +
               '<img src="../../assets/img/room-plan/' + r_plan + '" alt="..." id="imgsrc">' +
               '</div>'
               ,
               r_name,
               '<div class="text-right">' +
               '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>' +
               '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>' +
               '</div>'
    ]).draw(false);

    //var oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable();
    //aData = oTable.fnGetData();
    //var aReturn = [];

    //$(aData).each(function () {
    //    var nextRow = new Array();
    //    aReturn.push(nextRow);

    //});
    //console.log(aReturn[0]);

});
//-------------------------INSERT ROOM END----------------------------

$('#add-room-submit').click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I'd stay within the DataTables environment - you can just query the table itself to see if  `r_name` is present. DataTables caches the table so these searches are fast - so you don't need to keep another array:

```
t.column(1).data().toArray().includes(r_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer given by colino117, I solved the problem as follows:

```
var t = $('#datatables').DataTable();

//-------------------------INSERT ROOM START----------------------------
$("[name='add-room-submit']").click(function () {

    var r_name = document.getElementById('room-name').value;
    var r_plan = document.getElementById('image-path').value;

    t.row.add([
               '<div class="img-container">' +
               '<img src="../../assets/img/room-plan/' + r_plan + '" alt="..." id="imgsrc">' +
               '</div>'
               ,
               r_name.toUpperCase(),
               '<div class="text-right">' +
               '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>' +
               '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>' +
               '</div>'
    ]).draw(false);

//addition

   var oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable();
   aData = oTable.fnGetData();
   var ndx = 0;
   var count = 0;
   $(aData).each(function () {       
    if ( r_name.toUpperCase() == oTable.fnGetData()[ndx][1] ) {
        count++;
    }
    ndx++;
});
if (count > 1) {
    alert('Warning!');
}

//addition

});
//-------------------------INSERT ROOM END----------------------------

$('#add-room-submit').click();
```